# Finding the length between the two vertices of two different triangles having the same base side and same perimeter by a shorter method.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, conic-sections, area

[image: Here is the figure to give you a better idea about the problem]

***My approach:-***

1. Using distance formula I found the lengths of AC,CB and AB. Using them I found out the perimeter of
   triangle ABC and it came out to be 18 square units. Hence, $$AB+BC+CA=18 units$$
2. Then for triagle ABP, the perimeter can be written as sum of lengths of AB,AP and BP. Length of AB is
   8 units, that gives us the sum of lengths of AP and BP as 10 units. Hence,
   $$AP+BP=10 units$$
3. Found out the area of ABC is 12 units. That means the area of ABP is 6 units.
4. Assumed coordinates of P as (g,h). Hence the area of ABP should be, $\frac{(AB)(h)}{2}=6$. This gives
   us h=3/2.
5. To get 'g', I wrote the distance AP and BP using distance formula,added them and equated them to 10.
   This gives us an equation where 'g' is the only variable. And I found its value.

***What I am looking for:-***

A shorter method to solve this problem if there is any. Because my approach took a lot of calculations and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $AP+BP=AC+BC,$ we see that $P$ is placed on the ellipse with focuses $(-4,0)$ and $(4,0)$, which gives $c=4$ and $b=y_{A}=3$, which gives $a=5$ and an equation of the ellipse it's: $$\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{9}=1.$$

Also, from the given: $y_{P}=\frac{3}{2}.$

Can you end it now?

I got $PC=\sqrt{21}.$

Comment: How did you conclude that P is on an ellipse and found its equation as well?

Comment: @Dravit Gupta Because $AP+BP=AC+BC=2a=2\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=2\cdot5,$ $b=3$, $c=4$.

Comment: So if I ever encounter any situation where there are 4 points A,B,C and D and it's given that $CA+CB=AD+BD$, should I directly conclude that A and B are the foci of an ellipse on which C and D are lying? Or it depends from situation to situation?

Comment: @Dravit Gupta In your example we can say that $C$ and $D$ are placed on the ellipse with focuses $A$ and $B$, with $AC+BC=2a$.